# How to set Action Mailer defaults after config/initializers run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store email account information in a config.yml file.  I'm loading that information into a constant in a Rails config/initializers file following a common pattern I've seen online and outlined [at this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file).  I'm trying to setup defaults for Action Mailer using config.action_mailer.smtp_settings inside the config/application.rb file, following an example  on [Mat Harvard's Blog](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/).  I keep getting uninitialized constant errors when starting my rails server.  I'm assuming that application.rb is being called before the config/initializers.  Is there another location where I can set the config.action_mailer.smtp_settings during startup, but after the config/initializers run?

Update:
I may not have been clear in my initial post/question.  I'm reading the config.yml file in an initializer.  This config file stores email account information such as username and password.  I don't want to put this information (username and password) in either the application.rb or environment.rb files.  I did try moving my code to the environment.rb file, but encountered the same uninitialized constant error when starting rails.

My code to set the action mailer settings looks like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => APP_CONFIG[:email_config][:address],
    :port                 => APP_CONFIG[:email_config][:port],
    :domain               => APP_CONFIG[:email_config][:email_domain],
    :user_name            => APP_CONFIG[:email_config][:user_name],
    :password             => APP_CONFIG[:email_config][:password],
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => APP_CONFIG[:email_config][:host]
  }
```

I'm reading from the config.yml file to set the APP_CONFIG constant in a load_config.rb initializer.  That file contains the 2 lines below:

```
raw_config = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/config/config.yml")
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)[RAILS_ENV]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put something like this in an initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com' }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is use Figaro for environment variables:

```
# config/initializers/smtp_config.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { address: Figaro.env.smtp_address,
                                         port: (Figaro.env.smtp_port || 587),
                                         domain: Figaro.env.smtp_domain,
                                         user_name: Figaro.env.smtp_user_name,
                                         password: Figaro.env.smtp_password,
                                         authentication: Figaro.env.smtp_authentication,
                                         enable_starttls_auto: Figaro.env.smtp_enable_starttls_auto,
                                         openssl_verify_mode: Figaro.env.smtp_openssl_verify_mode,
                                         ssl: Figaro.env.smtp_ssl,
                                         tls: Figaro.env.smtp_tls }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An initializer probably isn't the right place for this information, at least not in Rails 3. Following the guidelines in the [official ActionMailer guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), I would put the information in the environment file -- I presume the definition of the constants will change depending on what environment you're in, and this will have the same effect. So in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Shamelessly stolen from the guide I just referenced.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid putting the username and password in either the application.rb or environment.rb files.  I've updated my original question/post to include code samples.  The config code you supplied above was not in the initializer - it was in application.rb.  Just the code to read in my config.yml file was in the initializer.

Comment: So Did you get the initializer to load before you enviroment files ?